# Java applet is not supporting the Authenticator.setDefault

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, applet, accesscontrolexception

I want to do simple HTTP authentication in a Java applet, which I am trying this way:

```
static class MyAuthenticator extends Authenticator
        {
            public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
                {
            // I haven't checked getRequestingScheme() here, since for NTLM
            // and Negotiate, the usrname and password are all the same.
            System.err.println("Feeding username and password for " + getRequestingScheme());
            return (new PasswordAuthentication(kuser, kpass.toCharArray()));
            }
        }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        try
        {
        //  String authenticate=Authenticator.getPasswordAuthentication();
             Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticator());
             URL url = new URL("http://Ip_address/jpg/image.jpg");
             InputStream ins = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins));
             String str;
               while((str = reader.readLine()) != null)
                  System.out.println(str);

          //int s=2+2;

            g.drawString("hello world", 50, 60 );
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception : "+ e);
        }
    }
```

But I am getting error at this line

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticator());
```

The exception is:

```
Exception : java.security.AccessControlException: access denied 
    (java.net.NetPermission setDefaultAuthenticator)
```

Can anyone tell me that what to do now, or how to authenticate a website inside from Java applet?

Answer (score 1):

You've run into a security sandbox restriction.  Apparently, it is a security concern for an untrusted applet to be changing the default authenticator.  (I imagine it is because a nasty applet could use this to steal authentication details supplied by the user.)

Whatever the reason for the restriction, one solution is to sign the JAR file for your applet.  See [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signing.html) of the Oracle Tutorials for details.

Comment: Is not there any command/method/class that can change the security parameters for the specific applet?

Comment: Not from within the applet.  That would defeat the purpose of security sandboxes.  (Q: what would be the first thing that nasty applet do?  A: turn off the security checks that prevent it from doing nasty things!)

Comment: So is there any other method that can do the basic Http Authentication in java applet?

Comment: I'm sure you can do Basic Authentication by setting the appropriate Headers (as per the RFC) using a hard-wired username and password.  The point of the `Authenticator` API is (typically) to ask the user to supply the information.  But it is an obvious security failure if an untrusted applet is allowed to ask the user to tell it that information via a UI that looks like it should be trusted.

Comment: Modifying global state in a shared environment is a really bad idea (not a great idea in other code either).

Comment: Yes, there is that too.  (OP - Tom is refering to the fact that there may be other (unrelated) applets running in the JVM. Changing the default authenticator in one applet will change it for others.)